# How to prevent blank page in react on http errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I see blank page in react application when the `axios` receives  `503 (Service Unavailable)`. 
I understand the issue. When there is `503 (service Unavailable)` error, component unmounts and eventually react shows blank page.

Is there any idea how to prevent the blank page?

Notes:

> 1. Errors are very well handled and I even see the error logs in browser console.
> 2. This is not happening in case of `500` errors

Comment: can you provide code snap?

Answer (score 0):

503 is a network error, which is not handed by axios, So you are not jumping to error handling code.
add some error check in your axios response interceptor.

```
if (error && error.message === 'Network Error') {
    throw new Error(`Network error`);
  }
```

Or you can simply reject the promise on any 'error'.

```
Promise.reject(error);
```

Comment: Error is handled but component unmounts which is the problem